# Is there a R function to predict the 95% confidence intervals around the predicted means of a multilevel regression model fitted in 'lme4'?

Tags: lme4

In RStudio/1.3.1093 I have fitted a unconditional natural cubic spline model (ucns) in 'lme4'.  I have a longitudinal subdataset with symptom data (symptoms: score 1 to 10) of 30 patients (record_id), measured at 31 time points (day). So the data consists of 3 coloms (record_id, time, symptoms) and 30x31 rows.

I have plotted this model by predicting the y-scores of every time point. Now I would also like to plot the 95% confidence intervals around the predicted scores.

I have fitted the ucns model is this way:

`ucns<- lmer(formula=symptoms~ns(time, df=7) + (time|record_id), data=symptomdata, na.action=na.omit, REML=FALSE)`

I have predicted the y-scores of this model in this way:

```
predsymptoms <- as.data.frame(1:31) %>%
  rename(time = (1)) %>%
  mutate(y.est.ucns = predict(ucns, predsymptoms, re.form=NA))
```

I would like to know which code I may use to predict the 95% confidence intervals around the predicted y.est.ucns values. Thank you in advance for your help.